# Let $f(x)=x^4+x^3+4x-1\in\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$. Let $K$ be the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$. Find $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Z}_5)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields, splitting-field

> Let $f(x)=x^4+x^3+4x-1\in\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$. Let $K$ be the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Z}_5$.  Find $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Z}_5)$.

So, the first thing we need to do is find the splitting field, and I am just sort of stuck. I know that $f(1)=0$, but I don't believe there are any more roots. So should I just use a primitive fourth root of unity? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think you should use a $4$-th root of unity? Even though your polynomial is of degree $4$ (well, $3$ as you've found one root) this stills makes extensions up to degree $4!=24$ for the splitting field possible!

Comment: Point of notation. By $\mathbb{Z}_5$ do you mean the $5$-adic integers or do you mean the finite field of order $5$?

Comment: @Teddy38 Finite field of order $5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have found *a* root, $f(1)=0$, but missed another one, $f(4)=0$. So, $f$ factors into the product of two linear polynomials (that we may ignore from hereon) and a quadratic polynomial $q$. Hence, the splitting field of $f$ is at most of degree $2$ (generated by either root of $q$) and hence, Galois with either Galois group $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ or trivial group (if $q$ splits over $\mathbb Z_5$ as well).

We have the following:

$$
f(x)=x^4+x^3+4x-1\equiv(x-1)(x-4)(x^2+x+1)\mod5
$$

So $q(x)=x^2+x+1$, which is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_5$ (as it has no roots). So $[K:\mathbb Z_5]=2$ and the rest follows as sketched above.

Comment: Ah, okay, I see!  Two questions: first, since $q$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_5$, the Galois Group is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, correct?  And not the trivial group?  But, how did you know that it had to be $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @User7238 Yes, $K=\mathbb Z_5(\alpha)\supsetneq\mathbb Z_5$ with $q(\alpha)=0$ and $\alpha\notin\mathbb Z_5$. Since $K$ is splitting field of $f$ but the only non-split part is $q$ we know that $K$ is equivalently the splitting field of $q$, which is a quadratic polynomial. Hence, $[K:\mathbb Z_5]\in\{1,2\}$. The splitting field will be Galois (since $\mathbb Z_5$ is perfect) implying that $|\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb Z_5)|\in\{1,2\}$. But there are not that many groups of order $1$ and $2$, respectively ;)

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much!

Comment: @User7238 Glad to help!